# Reopen question 'Chess principles for beginner'

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, specific-question

The question [Chess principles for beginner](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/24779/chess-principles-for-beginner) has been closed as too broad, but it is a very precise question about the validity and relevance of a particular set of principles. There is, in my honest opinion, no reason why this should be closed.

Answer (score 3):

If you think this question should be opened, you can cast a reopen vote; you have [enough reputation to do so](https://chess.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions). This will send the question into the [Reopen Votes review queue](http://chess.stackexchange.com/review/reopen) where other community members will judge on the fate of the question.

Before doing that, ask yourself whether the following article in the [Help Center](https://chess.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) applies:

> #### What types of questions should I avoid asking?
>
> ...
>
> You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.
>
> Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much.
>
> If your motivation for asking the question is “I would like to participate in a discussion about ______”, then you should not be asking here. However, if your motivation is “I would like others to explain ______ to me”, then you are probably OK. (Discussions are of course welcome in our real time web chat.)

I'm intended to say it does; people have written books about lists like these. Though to be fair, they'll expand each point with examples, otherwise it'll be a small book.

In general, [list type questions don't fare too well in the Stack Exchange format](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139618/295232). If you strongly agree with one item in the list but are vehemently opposed to another, should you up- or downvote? If you have a new item, should you add it to the list or write a new answer? What if you have multiple items to add?

Comment: Thank you! I was not aware of how that priviledge works!

Comment: You're welcome. It'll end up in the review queue after ~15 minutes ([here it is](https://chess.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/13769)); I'll skip that review since my decision would be binding and this is one of the instances where I prefer not to act (as mentioned in my [nomination](https://chess.stackexchange.com/election/1#post-24649)).